# What is sideways data loading in React?

Tags: reactjs

There are a few scattered references to "sideways data loading" in [various React issues](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3398) and elsewhere, but I haven't found a concise description of exactly what is meant by this term. Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 13):

sideways loading is the concept that data is pushed directly to specific components, instead of from the parents (as is done in the initial rendering / vanilla react without subscriptions or observables). So basically you are not re-rendering the app again from the root, but only a specific part of your component tree.

One approach to achieve this is using observables as described [here](http://mendix.com/tech-blog/making-react-reactive-pursuit-high-performing-easily-maintainable-react-apps/), and some flux frameworks help you with this as well.

Comment: so fundamentally it sounds like the same concept as module exports. Export things to a global space so anything anywhere can grab them as needed, as opposed to some permitted entities such as to children.